# Why does my 2015 Ford Fusion not want to start after putting gas

Tags: fuel-system, ignition

The last couple of months my car has a hard time starting when I put gas in it. It doesn’t matter if it’s half tank or almost empty. It started with sputtering and hesitation and now it just tried to turn over. Takes me a few times trying to start it to actually start! 
Once it’s started and I get on the road I don’t have anymore problems! Only when I put fuel in the car.

What do you think is the issue?

Comment: Are you getting fuel from the same gas-station each time?

Comment: Try disconnecting the purge solenoid vacuum line next time before you fill up and see if it happens again.

Comment: Have you tried leaving it running while you fuel up?